# ORA-02063 Encoding problem with Oracle querying SQL Server through ODBC link

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc, dblink

We have a problem querying some data from the SQL Server from the Oracle database with the **`ORA-LNX`** connecting to **`SQL-SRV`** using **`ODBC`** and `Heterogeneous Service` (Oracle HS).

When we send the query through the **`ORA-WND`** Oracle, the results are exactly as expected; everything works fine.

The problem occurs when we send the query through our production Oracle server, which is **`ORA-LNX`**. oth Oracle are configured with the same encoding (NLS) parameters, both have the same **`ODBC`** configuration as well.

Here is the error: 
ORA-02063 / ORA-28500
[image: ORA-02063 / ORA-28500]

This happens when it encounters a french accent: **`É`** which gets translated into  **`Ã‰`** on the **`ORA-LNX`** while it stays as an **`É`** when queried through **`ORA-WND`**...

**Configuration:**

- **`SQL-SRV`** : Microsoft SQL Server
- **`ORA-LNX`** : Oracle 12.1 : windows-1252 / AL16UTF16 on Linux
- **`ORA-WND`** : Oracle 12.1 : windows-1252 / AL16UTF16 on Windows

**Different tools used to reproduce the problem:**

- PL/SQL Developer (AllAroundAutomations)
- .NET application
- VB6 application

Comment: Hmm, what's `LANG` set to in a shell on the Linux box? Does anything stand out from the output of the `locale` command? When I've seen this sort of thing in the past, it's been the unixODBC configuration that's not been setup correctly